# Assign object keys to another object's keys dynamically

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

I have an array called `viewObject.terms`. This array can contain up to 3 items, I need to iterate through this array and save the values into a data object.

ie:

```
data.term_id_1 = viewObject.terms[0].term_id
data.ticker_1  = viewObject.terms[0].its_ticker
```

This is what I first tried, but I get the error: `Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

```
for (var i=0; i<viewObject.terms.length; i++) {
    data.term_id_[i+1] = viewObject.terms[i].term_id;
    data.ticker_[i+1]  = viewObject.terms[i].its_ticker;
}
```

[image: TypeError]

---

So for the moment, I'm just using a `switch` case to handle this currently (albeit in a super ugly way):

```
if (viewObject.terms.length > 0) {
    switch(viewObject.terms.length) {
        case 1:
            data.term_id_1 = viewObject.terms[0].term_id;
            data.ticker_1  = viewObject.terms[0].its_ticker;
            break;
        case 2:
            data.term_id_1 = viewObject.terms[0].term_id;
            data.ticker_1  = viewObject.terms[0].its_ticker;
            data.term_id_2 = viewObject.terms[1].term_id;
            data.ticker_2  = viewObject.terms[1].its_ticker;
            break;
        case 3:
            data.term_id_1 = viewObject.terms[0].term_id;
            data.ticker_1  = viewObject.terms[0].its_ticker;
            data.term_id_2 = viewObject.terms[1].term_id;
            data.ticker_2  = viewObject.terms[1].its_ticker;
            data.term_id_3 = viewObject.terms[2].term_id;
            data.ticker_3  = viewObject.terms[2].its_ticker;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: as phrased, this seems more akin to a stackoverflow type question, because you're receiving an error (exception)...  but it's likely answered already, and so it'll just be flagged as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution to the problem could be expressed using [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), as the following:

```
viewObject.terms.forEach(function(term, index){
    data['term_id_' + (index + 1)] = term.term_id;
    data['ticker_'  + (index + 1)] = term.its_ticker;
});
```

Comment: This one is more elegant than the author's own conclusion. `votes++;` :-)

Comment: yeah, that's one way of doing it, but the link you referenced actually provides a sample on how to make a CopyTo function on objects.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out! Hope my answer helps someone else:

```
for (var i=0; i<viewObject.terms.length; i++) {
    data['term_id_'+(i+1)] = viewObject.terms[i].term_id;
    data['ticker_'+(i+1)]  = viewObject.terms[i].its_ticker;
}
```

This is how you dynamically name and iterate keys inside of an object